# Laravel Database Join sql or Array join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have two tables:

1. outgo_table

   - 1.1 daily_money_column
   - 1.2 created_at_column
2. income_table**

   - 2.1 daily_money_column
   - 2.2 created_at_column

What I want to select?

1. I want to select sum of daily_money_column using created_at_column from two table
2. I want to join them with daily created_column

for example:
 **outgo_table**

---

```
|daily_money_column| created_at_column    |
|    100           |  2018-07-15 13:21:00 |
|    150           |  2018-07-14 13:44:00 |
|    200           |  2018-07-14 13:11:00 |
|    170           |  2018-07-12 13:14:00 |
|    500           |  2018-07-11 13:48:00 |
```

**income_table**

```
|daily_money_column| created_at_column    |
|    200           |  2018-07-15 13:42:00 |
|    300           |  2018-07-15 13:42:00 |
|    200           |  2018-07-13 13:42:00 |
|    200           |  2018-07-11 13:42:00 |
|    200           |  2018-07-11 13:42:00 |
|    50000         |  2018-07-10 13:42:00 |
```

I want such a result ?

```
| daily_money_column_from_outgo | daily_money_column_from_income | created_at |
|    100                        |             500*               | 2018-07-15 |
|    350                        |              0                 | 2018-07-14 |
|    0                          |             200                | 2018-07-13 |
|    170                        |              0                 | 2018-07-12 |
|    500                        |             400                | 2018-07-11 |
|    0                          |            50000               | 2018-07-10 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

```
DB::table('outgo_table')->select(array(
    DB::raw('sum(outgo_table.daily_money_column)'),
    DB::raw('sum(income_table.daily_money_column)'),
    DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(income_table.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")')
))->join('income_table', function($query){
    $query->on(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(outgo_table.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")'), '=', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(income_table.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")'))
})->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(income_table.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")'))
  ->get();
```

Comment: How can I make full Join?

Comment: What do you mean by full join ?

Comment: this sql command does not give me the result as I want . It is just give me when the date is equal in two tables, but I want all result.

Comment: If there exist a record in the outgo table that does not exist in the income_table and you need it in the result set, you need to use left join.
And for the reverse scenario you need to use right join.